# How can I treat with NULL as minimum value?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table like this:

```
// notifications
+----+-----------+-------+---------+---------+------+
| id |   score   | type  | post_id | user_id | seen |
+----+-----------+-------+---------+---------+------+
| 1  | 15        | 1     | 2342    | 342     | 1    |
| 2  | 5         | 1     | 2342    | 342     | 1    |
| 3  | NULL      | 2     | 5342    | 342     | 1    |
| 4  | -10       | 1     | 2342    | 342     | NULL |
| 5  | 5         | 1     | 2342    | 342     | NULL |
| 6  | NULL      | 2     | 8342    | 342     | NULL |
| 7  | -2        | 1     | 2342    | 342     | NULL |
+----+-----------+-------+---------+---------+------+
-- type: 1 means "it is a vote", 2 means "it is a comment (without score)"
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(score), type, post_id, seen
FROM notifications
WHERE user_id = 342
GROUP BY type, post_id
ORDER BY (seen IS NULL) desc
```

As you see, there is `SUM()` function, Also both `type` and `post_id` columns are in the `GROUP BY` statement. Well now I'm talking about `seen` column. I don't want to put it into `GROUP BY` statement. So I have to use either `MAX()` or `MIN()` for it. Right?

Actually I need to select `NULL` as `seen` column *(in query above)* if there is even one row which has `seen = NULL`. My current query selects `1` as `seen`'s value, even when I use `MIN(seen)`. So why `1` is minimum when there is `NULL`?

Also I want to order rows so that all `SEEN = NULL` be in the top of list. How can I do that?

---

**Expected result:**

```
// notifications
+-----------+-------+---------+------+
|   score   | type  | post_id | seen |
+-----------+-------+---------+------+
| 13        | 1     | 2342    | NULL |
| NULL      | 2     | 8342    | NULL |
| NULL      | 2     | 5342    | 1    |
+-----------+-------+---------+------+
```

Comment: From your sample data, what are your expected results?

Comment: @zerkms Why you didn't use neither `max()` or `min()` for `seen` column?

Comment: @zerkms No ..! The whole my question is about `max` and `min`. You know, `SUM()` replaces some rows (that have identical `type` and `post_id`) with one row. Right? So in this case what's the value of `seen` column?

Comment: Lots of comments back and forth -- confusion obviously -- please post your expected results...  As is, it appears others are just guessing.

Comment: @sgeddes Updated ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```
   case when sum(seen is null) > 0 
        then null 
        else min(seen)
   end
```

Comment: This appears to be the correct answer (upvoted for figuring it out without sample results!)... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7781f7/1

Comment: Sorry to ping you again. But I've changed the default value of `seen` column, it is `0` now *(it was `NULL` already)*. So there is either `0` or `1` *(and there isn't `NULL` at all anymore)*. So can you please tell me how can I do that now?

Comment: just use `min(seen)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(score), type, post_id, min(IFNULL(seen, 0)) as seen
FROM notifications
WHERE user_id = 342
GROUP BY type, post_id
ORDER BY seen desc
```

Comment: Why you didn't use `MIN()` for `seen` in `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Because I used seen as alias for min(IFNULL(seen, 0)) @MartinAJ

Comment: Do you mean that `seen` in the `ORDER  BY` clause refers to that alias? If you change it to `as seen1`, then the `ORDER BY` also will be `ORDER BY seen1 desc` ?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can use practically any alias @MartinAJ

Comment: Well [it doesn't work as expected](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7781f7/2) .. thank you anyway

Comment: I guess it works as expected instead of null you see 0 and you can change ORDER BY seen desc to ORDER BY seen asc and will see the same result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7781f7/6 @MartinAJ

Comment: Just for my information, why did you write `asc` in the `ORDER BY` clause? I think if you remove it *(just write this `ORDER BY seen`)*, then the result is still the same, am I right?